# SQL schema to for efficient ORDER BY after filtering using WHERE ... IN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `widgets`, where each widget has a `group_id` and a `creation_date`. I'd like to run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM widgets
WHERE group_id IN (1, 2, 3)
ORDER BY creation_date;
```

How do I best design my schema to make the query efficient? It feels like no matter how I index this, I'll either have an index-less sort step after filtering, or an index-less filter step after sorting.

Current schema and query plan:

```
postgres=# \d widgets;
                        Table "public.widgets"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
group_id      | integer                     |           | not null |
creation_date | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "a" btree (creation_date)
    "b" btree (group_id)
    "c" btree (group_id, creation_date)
    "d" btree (creation_date, group_id)

postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE group_id in (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY creation_date;
                                                    QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sort  (cost=15.88..15.96 rows=31 width=12) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
Sort Key: creation_date
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on widgets  (cost=4.69..15.12 rows=31 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (group_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on c  (cost=0.00..4.68 rows=31 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
            Index Cond: (group_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))
Planning Time: 0.558 ms
Execution Time: 0.067 ms
(9 rows)
```

Note that this is on an empty table in a development database, so the times are irrelevant.

Comment: How many rows do you expect after filtering?

Comment: This could be up to 5 thousand.

Comment: Please [tag your RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: In theory if you had an index on `group_id, creation_date` it would be possible to do three equality seeks and merge union the three sorted results to produce a result sorted by `creation_date` without any additional sort - in SQL Server this would need a query rewrite to get this plan though. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE group_id = 1 UNION SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE group_id = 2 UNION SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE group_id = 3`, because I think this would be only be ordered by `creation_date` within each group, not overall.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the details of the current explain plan?

Comment: @JonathanR - `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` and it would need an `ORDER BY`. And SQL Server could certainly do this as I describe. But as you have now clarified that you are using Postgres this is academic anyway

Comment: Wouldn't the last order by (after unioning the 3 groups) require an index-less quicksort, regardless of the choice or RDBMS?

Comment: @JonathanR - No. If you have three ordered inputs you can use an approach similar to merge join to produce a combined ordered result without any sorting. But I have no idea if Postgres will do a merge union

Comment: If you want to analyze the performance of a query you will have to do that with a table that contains a realistic number of rows. Please show us the execution plan (generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` against a table with data.

Comment: The current query on the current data is lightning fast, there is not much you can optimise. Can you fill the table with real production data that also has the volume you expect?

Comment: Sorting "up to 5 thousand rows" should be pretty much instant.  Don't solve problems that don't exist.  Martin Smith is onto something, PostgreSQL can do this optimization but you have to back it into a corner and twist its arm to get it to do it.  Writing your queries in contorted ways to solve problems that don't exist is an investment with a negative return.

Comment: You must drop the notation that **Use Index = Run Fast**. The table definition as presented has 12 byets for each row, allowing for some overhead this means each data block will contain about 400 rows. Now keep in mind using an index requires a minimum of 2 physical IOs. In this case an using an index is probably vastly slower because of the increase in physical IO.   Give it a test: create 1M rows with 1000 groups, analyze the table, then retry your query.  As it stands you query execution time is less than 100ms; that is literally the blink on an eye,

Comment: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Comment: The best solution depends on undisclosed information. Most importantly: Cardinalities of table and each column, and the number of groups per query. Filtering by a set of values in one column and sorting by another is tricky to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend that you create many indexes for a table. As you know, many indexes reduce the performance of the `insert` and `update` processes. You only need to create indexes for these `fields`, which be used frequently in `where` conditions, on `order by` and `group by` commands, in `join` conditions. If in `where` conditions always we use two fields together, then recommend creating one index for these two fields.

In this script: you create 4 indexes for 2 fields. You need to decide for which fields we must to create indexes, creating indexes for all fields and for all options is not recommended.